# I need to solve a limit without using l'Hopital rule

Tags: limits, functions, limits-without-lhopital

i need to solve this limit without using l'Hopital rule. Thanks in advance if you'll answer.
$$\lim\limits _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{-4x}-1}{x^2-x}\right)$$

Comment: It's rather unfortunate that questions phrased in this manner get so many complete answers so quickly; it's a real pity that so many of the answers robbed the asker of the opportunity to learn something by doing it themselves. I suppose that those few reputation points are far more important.... Voting to close as missing-context, because the asker has not included any of their own thoughts or efforts on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that

$$\frac{e^{-4x}-1}{x^2-x}=\frac1{e^{4x}}\frac{1-e^{4x}}{4x}\frac{4x}{x^2-x}=\frac1{e^{4x}}\frac{e^{4x}-1}{4x}\frac{4}{1-x}\to1\cdot1 \cdot 4=4$$

Comment: Why the downvote? I gave the full answer only after it was given by user284331

Comment: But you know, these kind of limits without L'Hopital, there are many circumstances that full answers are provided, sometimes got downvote, sometimes not, there is no standard at all.

Comment: @user284331 when the limit is simple and the asker don't show much work and effort on it I think that it should be better provide only some good hints

Comment: You got some point. But the downvoter should put a note in my comment box, rather just putting downvote and then goes away.

Comment: @Isham Thanks for your appreciation, it is not a problem for downvotes, I receive a lot of them but fortunately much lesser than upvotes! :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch man. Unfortunately i cannot upvote you.

Comment: @Musna I upvoted you, now you are at 13, maybe at 15 you'll be able! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 4):

$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}{{e^{-4x}-1}\over x}=-4$ (the derivative of $e^{-4x}$ at $0$), $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}{x\over {x^2-x}}=-1$. Take the product of the limits.

Comment: Err, but the question asks $e^{-4x}$, not $e^{4x}$...

Comment: Note that the numerator is ${e^{-4x}-1}$

Comment: Despite the error you received many upvotes and I downvotes, It is good for you :)

Comment: @gimusi how do you know it was downvoted ? I upvoted despite the error

Comment: @Isham Wait until you get more points and you will see it too.

Comment: Oh I understand now...@AOlov

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\dfrac{e^{-4x}-1}{x^{2}-x}&=\dfrac{(1-4x+(16x^{2}/2)-\cdots)-1}{x^{2}-x}\\
&=\dfrac{8x-4-\cdots}{x-1}\\
&\rightarrow 4
\end{align*}
as $x\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: we have given an hint to let some work to the asker, but if you give a full solution we are forced to give it too

Comment: Okay, I got you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

That is my answer for the limit, it is a image...

Comment: Is this correct? 'cause i don't know that infinitesimal rule and i cannot confirm it, can anyone else confirm if this is correct?

Comment: @Musna Yes t is a correct approach in this case since we need a first order expansion (which correspond to 1 application of L'Hopital) but in the general case we can't be sure that a first order expansion suffices and it should be better use it with little-o or big-O notation.